# how to create dependent picklist in vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app, visualforce-component, multi-select

I am having a multiselect picklist in that am displaying the list of profiles in the org using SOQL Query.My usecase is like when i click on any profile/profiles those related applications should be displayed in another dropdown

I have a SOQL query to fetch the list of applications in the org but i am not sure how to render the profile related application in a dropdown dynamically.Any help would be appriciated

This is how i am querying the application

```
  public List<SelectOption> getApps()
 {
   List<String> profileName = new List<String>();
   List<AppMenuItem> apps= [ SELECT Name FROM AppMenuItem WHERE Type = 'TabSet' ];
  list<SelectOption>  lstOptions = new list<SelectOption>();
  for(AppMenuItem app: apps){
      lstOptions.add(new SelectOption(app.Name,app.Name));
  }
  return lstOptions;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You just need to have variables or methods to calculate what the values should be. Here's an example that should work in any org. You'll want to read more about [apex:actionSupport](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm#!) in the documentation.

---

```
public class q249304 {
    public Id[] profileIds { get; set; }
    public Id[] userIds { get; set; }

    // Renders a list of options for profiles
    public SelectOption[] getProfiles() {
        SelectOption[] results = new SelectOption[0];
        for(Profile record: [SELECT Name FROM Profile ORDER BY Name]) {
            results.add(new SelectOption(record.Id, record.Name));
        }
        return results;
    }
    // Renders a list of users that have the selected profiles, if any
    public SelectOption[] getUsers() {
        SelectOption[] results = new SelectOption[0];
        if(profileIds != null) {
            for(User record:[SELECT Name FROM User WHERE ProfileId = :profileIds ORDER BY Name]) {
                results.add(new SelectOption(record.Id, record.Name));
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="q249304">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:selectList label="Profiles" multiselect="true" value="{!profileIds}" size="5">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!profiles}" />
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="users" />
                </apex:selectList>
                <apex:selectList id="users" label="User" multiselect="true" value="{!userIds}" size="5">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!users}" />
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="userList" />
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="userList">
                Selected Users: {!userIds}
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```